# How to monitor JBoss active threads of a web application via JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement to monitor JBoss active threads (of an application under test) while I am performing load test through JMeter.

After going through different articles, I came across 2 JMeter which may help in getting this info.

[PerfMon Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

[JMXMon Sampler Collector](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/)

I want to know which one of these two will be suitable for my requirement. Right now, I have PerfMon listener in working condition in my setup so it will be preferable if someone can share a solution where I can get the JBoss active thread statistics using PerfMon listener alone!

Comment: Both of those wouldn't show you active threads unless you went in and modified the plugin source code manually. Does it have to be through jmeter? You could use jconsole on the server for monitoring those threads.